# What numerical approach should I take with solving this system of 2nd order coupled ODEs?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I want to solve this system numerically, but I am stuck as to how to proceed.  Do I need to transform this into a set of four 1st order equations before discretizing?  Which numerical method would be recommended here?

$ \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} = \omega^2 x + 2\omega\frac{dy}{dt} $

$ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} = \omega^2 y - 2\omega\frac{dx}{dt} $

Thanks!

Comment: Should it be $\omega^2 y$ in the second equation? If it is, you can try solving $z = x + iy$

Comment: Yes, it should be.  Thanks for the catch.  I fixed the error and will look into your suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $z = x + iy$, where $z$ is a complex-valued function. Then

\begin{align} \frac{d^2z}{dt^2} &= \frac{d^2x}{dt^2} + i\frac{d^2y}{dt^2} \\
&= \omega^2(x + iy) + 2\omega\left(\frac{dy}{dt} - i\frac{dx}{dt}\right) \\
&= \omega^2(x + iy) - 2i\omega\left(i\frac{dy}{dt} + \frac{dx}{dt}\right) \\
&= \omega^2z - 2\omega i\frac{dz}{dt} \end{align}

---

**Solution:** Rearranging terms

$$ \frac{d^2z}{dt^2} + 2\omega i \frac{dz}{dt} - \omega^2 z = 0 $$

The characteristic polynomial is

$$ r^2 + 2\omega ir - \omega^2 = (r + i\omega)^2 = 0 $$

which gives a double root, and a general analytic solution of

$$ z(t) = (c_1 + c_2t)e^{-i\omega t} $$

Take the real and imaginary parts to get

\begin{align} 
x(t) &= (c_1+c_2t)\cos(\omega t) \\ y(t) &= -(c_1+c_2t)\sin(\omega t) 
\end{align}

Comment: I appreciate the hint, Dylan.  It seems like you are suggesting that there is an analytic solution?  Or are you suggesting that I discretize the above ODE, solve that numerically then look for the real and imaginary components of z and equate them to x(t) and y(t)?  I have not numerically solved complex valued ODEs before.  Would an Euler method work for something like that one?

Thanks!

Comment: The ODE in $z$ is linear with constant coefficients. What does that imply?

Comment: I will have to look at it more tomorrow.  When I initially plug in your suggested substitution I do not get the cancellations I expected and so I do not find the system you list as being equivalent to the two I list.

Comment: I've edited my answer to show more working